# input radio зависимости

Tags: javascript, html, css

введите сюда кодЕсть 2 блока с различными input radio блоками. В каждом по 3 варианта выбора. Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе в первом блоке радиокнопок, скажем, первого варианта, во втором блоке сразу же пропадал 1 вариант выбора, и оставалось только 2?

```html
<form>
        <h2>Выберите форму каркаса</h2>
        <div class="types">
          <div class="block">
            <div class="x1"><input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" value="1" checked><label for="tab1"></label><p>Классическая</p></div>
            <div class="x2"><img src="img/f1.png" alt="Штакет"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="x1"><input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs" value="2"><label for="tab2"></label><p>С прямыми стенками</p></div>
            <div class="x2"><img src="img/f2.png" alt="Шахматка"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="x1"><input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs" value="3"><label for="tab3"></label><p>По митлайдеру</p></div>
            <div class="x2"><img src="img/f3.png" alt="Ранчо"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Выберите размер теплицы</h2>
        <div class="widthx">
          <p>Ширина</p>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="x1"><input id="tab12" type="radio" name="tabs2" value="1" checked><label for="tab12"></label></div>
            <div class="x2"><p>2.5м</p></div>
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="x1"><input id="tab22" type="radio" name="tabs2" value="2"><label for="tab22"></label></div>
            <div class="x2"><p>3м</p></div>
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="x1"><input id="tab32" type="radio" name="tabs2" value="3"><label for="tab32"></label></div>
            <div class="x2"><p>4м</p></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lengthx">
          <p>Длина</p>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="x1"><input id="tab13" type="radio" name="tabs3" value="1" checked><label for="tab13"></label></div>
            <div class="x2"><p>4м</p></div>
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="x1"><input id="tab23" type="radio" name="tabs3" value="2"><label for="tab23"></label></div>
            <div class="x2"><p>6м</p></div>
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="x1"><input id="tab33" type="radio" name="tabs3" value="3"><label for="tab33"></label></div>
            <div class="x2"><p>8м</p></div>
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="x1"><input id="tab43" type="radio" name="tabs3" value="4"><label for="tab43"></label></div>
            <div class="x2"><p>10м</p></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stepx">
          <p>Шаг Дуг</p>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="x1"><input id="tab14" type="radio" name="tabs4" value="1" checked><label for="tab14"></label></div>
            <div class="x2"><p>1м</p></div>
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="x1"><input id="tab24" type="radio" name="tabs4" value="2"><label for="tab24"></label></div>
            <div class="x2"><p>0.65м</p></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button id="gocalc" type="submit">Рассчитать</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: вложи код!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: вложил но толку то от него?

Comment: поражаюсь если честно иногда русскому комьюнити. задал как-то вопрос тупой, так он набрал 20 рейтинга, хотя ни ответа ни толком вопроса не было. создал здравый вопрос, с понятной сутью, зафигачили минусами...

Comment: [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) Вам в помощь. Вешайте событие на чек первых инпутов и удаляйте нужные вторые, и так далее. В теории можно сделать так: ловите когда инпут чекнулся, берете его `id`, и удаляете исходя из `id`+ что-то добавочное из второго пункта.

Comment: @PaulWall сейчас зафигачили минусами, потому что вопрос напоминает что-то из разряда - сделайте за меня - нету попытки кода который Вам нужен)

Comment: @PaulWall у тебя никогда не было вопроса с рейтингом 20, не льсти себе))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В том виде что в коде - только скрипты. Можно чистым css, но тогда все input'ы должны быть "детьми" одного "родителя". Для примера:

```css
#background_color_red:checked ~ #font_color_red,
#background_color_red:checked ~ #font_color_red + label {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: gray;
}
#background_color_green:checked ~ #font_color_green,
#background_color_green:checked ~ #font_color_green + label {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: gray;
}
#background_color_blue:checked ~ #font_color_blue,
#background_color_blue:checked ~ #font_color_blue + label {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<h3>Background color</h3>
<input type=radio name=background_color id=background_color_red />
<label for=background_color_red>Red</label>
<input type=radio name=background_color id=background_color_green />
<label for=background_color_green>Green</label>
<input type=radio name=background_color id=background_color_blue />
<label for=background_color_blue>Blue</label>

<h3>Font color</h3>
<input type=radio name=font_color id=font_color_red />
<label for=font_color_red>Red</label>
<input type=radio name=font_color id=font_color_green />
<label for=font_color_green>Green</label>
<input type=radio name=font_color id=font_color_blue />
<label for=font_color_blue>Blue</label>
```

p.s. И да, если опция уже выбрана и должна быть заблокирована, то таким образом с неё выбор не снимется.

p.p.s. Можно вместо имитации `disable` скрывать опцию c `display: none;`

Comment: а если через jquery? чтобы снимался выбор

Comment: @PaulWall для `:radio` можно так: `$('#background_color_red').on('change',function(){
    $('input[id^=font_color]').prop('disabled',false);
    $('#font_color_red').prop('disabled',true).prop('checked',false);
});`, для `:checkbox` перед блокированием элемента надо проверять его значение, например `if ($(this).prop('checked')) ..../*блокируем что нужно*/`